# Lock-free simple segregated storage algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, lock-free

I'm working on a lock-free version of the "[**Simple Segregated Storage**](http://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/boost/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/simple_segregated_storage.html)" memory pool in C++.

The SSS memory pool is similar to a slab allocator : it's basically just a chunk of memory that is divided into blocks of equal sizes, and we have a free list pointer pointing to the first available block.  Allocating is simply moving the pointer up to the next block, and deallocating is simply setting the free list pointer to the deallocated block, and pointing the "next" pointer on the deallocated block to the old value of the freelist pointer.

So it's basically a singly-linked list.

Now, I'm trying to code a lock-free version of the Simple Segregated Storage algorithm.  If we assume that SEGREGATING the initial block of memory (i.e. creating the linked list) is always done *before* entering a multi-threaded environment, we only need to worry about allocating and deallocating blocks - in which case this problem becomes very similar to a lock-free singly linked-list, which is a well understood problem.

So, it seems to me that allocating and deallocating could easily be done in a lock-free manner by using simple compare and swap instructions.

Assuming we have the following free list pointer:

```
std::atomic<unsigned char*> m_first
```

And assume we have a helper function, `nextof()`, which takes in a block pointer and returns a reference to the "next pointer".  The next pointer is actually embedded within the memory block - so the `nextof` function looks like this:

```
unsigned char*& nextof(void* ptr)
{
    return *static_cast<unsigned char**>(ptr);
}
```

That's at least how the [Boost library implements Simple Segregated Storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/implementation/simple_segregated_storage.html).

Anyway, my attempt at a lock-free, atomic `allocate` function is:

```
void* malloc()
{
    unsigned char* first = m_first.load();
    if (!first) return nullptr;

    while (!m_first.compare_exchange_strong(first, nextof(first))) 
    {
        if (!first) break;
    }

    return first;
}
```

So - this seems very straightforward.  All we need to do is atomically set `m_first` to the next pointer embedded within the block pointed to by `m_first`.  Initially, I thought this would be as simple as saying `m_first.store(nextof(m_first))` - but unfortunately I don't think that's atomic because we're actually doing a store and a load here on the same memory location - we're storing a new value into `m_first`, but also loading the value of `m_first` in order to get it's next pointer.

So, it seems we need to do a Compare and Swap.  In the above code, I atomically load the value of `m_first` into a local variable.  Then, after checking for null, I atomically change the value of `m_first` with a CAS, if and only if it still equals the value of the local variable.  If it doesn't, the local variable is updated to whatever `m_first` is now, and we keep looping until we're not preempted by some other thread.

The deallocation is a bit trickier - here we need to change the value of `m_first` to the deallocated block, and *also* update the next pointer on the deallocated block to point to what `m_first` used to be.

My attempt at this is:

```
void free(void* chunk)
{
    unsigned char* first = m_first.load();
    nextof(chunk) = first;

    while (!m_first.compare_exchange_strong(first, static_cast<unsigned char*>(chunk)))
    {
        nextof(chunk) = first;
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure I have this right, but I think it's correct.  Firstly, I atomically load the value of `m_first` and store it in a local variable.  I then set the next pointer on the block-to-be-free'd to my local copy of `m_first`.  Of course, by now, another thread could have intervened and set `m_first` to something else - so I have to now do a CAS operation to check that `m_first` is still what I expect.  If it's not, I have to set the next pointer to the appropriate value, and continue looping.

As far as I can see this is all race-condition safe, with a single CAS operation for `malloc` and `free`.

**Question**: Since lock-free algorithms are hard, I'm not certain I have this correct.  Am I overlooking something here that could lead to a race condition?

Comment: You say "so" a lot. Also are you sure this doesn't belong on [codereview.se]?

Comment: [See item 2 & 3 of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920539/multithread-queue-atomic-operations/25984177#25984177).

Comment: If this is home work, it sounds like a fun class.  If your goal is a good memory allocator, I suggest having a free list per thread using thread local storage is better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, perhaps - I'm not sure why you think there is a correlation between the frequency of the word "so" and appropriateness for Code Review over Stackoverflow

Comment: @Siler: I don't. That's why I said "also" between the two statements.

Answer (score 0):

An old answer, but I thought I might give an opinion. Unless I am mistaken, I believe the code might leak data through a version of the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem).

The problem is the evaluation of the parameter `nextof(first)` before passing it to the atomic `compare_exchange_strong` inside `malloc`. If we take the `while` loop from the `malloc` function:

```
while (!m_first.compare_exchange_strong(first, nextof(first)))
{
    if (!first) return nullptr;
}
```

and rewrite it to explicitly evaluate `nextof(first)` before passing to `compare_exchange_strong`, to make it more obvious:

```
while (true)
{
    auto tmp_next = nextof(first);

    // this is where the chance for ABA exists

    if (m_first.compare_exchange_strong(first, tmp_next))
        break;

    if (!first) return nullptr;
}
```

Then there seems to be a possibility for `m_first` to change to a different value and back between these two lines, with another thread mutating actual `nextof(m_first)` in the meanwhile:

```
// I will represent the linked list using letters,
// i.e. m_first -> "A" means that "A" is at the head,
// and "A" -> "B" means that "A" points to "B"

void* malloc()
{
    // at the start, m_first points to "A": m_first -> "A" -> "B" -> "C"
    unsigned char* first = m_first.load();

    // --> thread #2 calls malloc() here and acquires "A", and
    //     removes it, so: m_first -> "B" -> "C"

    if (!first) return nullptr;

    while (true)
    {
        unsigned char * tmp_next = nextof(first);
        // tmp_next is "B" at this moment, because 'first' is still "A"            

        // --> some third thread returns some even older object now,
        //     so m_first -> "M" -> "B" -> "C"

        // --> thread #2 now calls free() to return "A", resulting in
        //     my_first -> "A" -> "M" -> "B" -> "C"

        // m_first is now back to "A", but tmp_next points
        // to old "B" instead of "M", and the following line succeeds
        // and "M" is lost forever: m_first -> "B" -> "C"

        if (m_first.compare_exchange_strong(first, tmp_next))
            break;

        if (!first) return nullptr;
    }

    return first;
}
```

The [Wikipedia article on ABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) contains some suggestions for solving these, like "tagged state reference" (basically adding something like a "transaction counter" to these pointers so that you can detect that the second "A" is not the same as the first one), or "intermediate nodes" which I find slightly more complex to implement (apparently invented by [John D. Valois in this article](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bushl2/rpi/portfolio/lockfree-grape/documents/lock-free-linked-lists.pdf)).